# Constant data in test database required to pass any tests

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have some data in my db. 70% of features depends on it. Even in model test i need them to persist. What is the best solution to manage it during my tests?

I was using before :suit and runing all seeds with them before each test suit (and clear them after suit).

But atm it takes additional few seconds before each suit. That is quite annoying  and ugly.

Maybe just runing seed after creating test DB and don't edit/destroy records in those tables during tests is better solution?

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If you require **ALL** of the data for **EVERY** test, you probably aren't testing correctly. I think you should look into factories, and only create the data you need when you need it.

Comment: Well i dont need all of them, but almost 70% of test require some of them, and i think creating them every time is not the best idea. Also all those data will be in my db always , so testing case that " they are not in my db" isn't the best idea because it will never happen. I know that db should be empty so we test only simple cases is the rule. But if every single case depends of some existing data that is the same in almost every single test?

Comment: Maybe your code is to tightly coupled if everything needs the same setup. Hard to tell without seeing the tests. You could use the default Rails fixtures to setup your tests, if you dont want to change the way you test.

Comment: Ok since i wrote that post, i learned that this situation is effect of bad written tests, and bad architecture. Thx for comments